# Android:When a module is loaded into call stack?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a newbie question about module loading into call stack in react native 0.70 app with Android. Is a native module loaded into call stack ONLY when the component which imports the module is called? Or as soon as the React Native app is launched, every native module is loaded into call stack no matter how late it is imported in the react native app, given a fact that there are config change (in android/settings.gradle, MainApplication.java and such) when the native module was installed.